# Is it possible for SharpSvn to retrieve log messages by author?

Tags: .net, svn, sharpsvn

As per the title of the question, I’m wondering if there’s any mechanism to invoke GetLog with an author parameter. Nothing is jumping out at me in the documentation either for GetLog or SvnLogArgs.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Alternative suggestions on how to do this are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't immediately see how either.

Assuming there isn't a direct filter, you can always filter it out yourself with the events and only save the ones with the relevant author. Sample code something like:

```
using(SvnClient client = NewSvnClient()){
    SvnLogArgs logArgs = new SvnLogArgs();

    client.Log(repofolder,
        logArgs,
        delegate(object sender, SvnLogEventArgs ea)
        {
            if( ea.Author != "silky" ){
                return;
            }

            // Save it ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Subversion doesn't have an API to filter on the server/repository based on specific fields, so this is the only option.